# Load data from file and create html elements in electron js

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, ipcrenderer, ipcmain

## What is expected:

Coming from Flask-JS I had a web app kind of thing that would read from a JSON file and create html elements based on that all by Jinja2 and that data would come from python (`Everything Normal!`).

## How do I perform this in Electron?

I have tried the documentation (*may be I am lacking there to understand*) but did not work. I went to well known AIs and they give me some ipcMain and ipcRenderer option but again I don't know it is my system or luck or else they throw TypeError.

**I am new to Electron and whole Node.js world, I know survival level of JS.**